# How do I insert a value for an element of an array that is pointed by a pointer in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I currently have a struct that contains a pointer to an array of pointers. I am trying to give a value to an element in the array of pointers, but I get a segmentation fault.

```
aStruct->anArray[0]->string = test;
```

aStruct contains a char** anArray and char *string.
char *test = "test".

When I try to do what I did, I get a segmentation fault. Is that command not valid?

```
struct aStruct
{
   char **anArray;
};
```

I used calloc to make an array of size 10.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> aStruct->anArray[0]->string = test;
> ```
>
> aStruct contains a char** anArray and char *string. char *test =
>   "test".
>
> Is that command not valid?

Certainly not. `aStruct->anArray[0]` would be `char*` and wouldn't have a member `->string`.

Other than that, if it really compiles and you only posted the wrong code, you wouldn't get a segmentation fault if `anArray` was properly allocated and had the right size. So you need something like this in your program:

```
aStruct->anArray = malloc(size * sizeof(*aStruct->anArray));
```

where size is at least one for your case, but generally the number of elements you ever need to access.